# Smack Configuration file not found

Tags: android, smack

I'm using Smack-3.4.0 API  to develop a chat application on Android(Basically this was an app which I created an year and a half ago and completely forgotten, with earlier version Smack API). The app was running fine earlier that time. Now I started using Smack-3.4.0 API (I just replaced older jar files with newer ones).

When i run my application try to open an XMPP connection i'm getting a message stating "SmackConfiguration : No configuration file found". The exception gives me a message "XMPP Error connection to x.x.x.x:5222"

Basically i'm getting "Connection refused" and that port is open on my system.

Please help me resolve this.

Comment: have you solved?.. I am facing same issue..

Comment: Yes,  the port was blocked by firewall. Check if the port isn't blocked on your system.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the problem was that the port was not open. I had to open the port from command line.

Comment: I am facing same issue, though my port is open as well, any suggestions?

Comment: Check if adding this function configure(ProviderManager.getInstance()), described in the following [link helps](http://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/31118)